# Cannot instantiate a binary_function for std::less / std::greater

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, stl, functional-programming

I'm trying to write a function that will print the contents of both minheap and maxheap but I'm having trouble with the comparators.  I tried using a ternary operator, but it doesn't work since std::less and std::greater are different types.  What is wrong with how I am trying to use the comparators?

```
#include <functional>
template<typename T> void printheap (T* v, int begin, int end, bool max) {
    end--;

    std::binary_function<T,T,bool> comp;
    if (max) comp = less<T>();
    else comp = greater<T>();

    while (end>=begin) {
        cout << v[begin] << " ";
        pop_heap(&v[begin], &v[end+1], comp );
        end--;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

---

Link error:

`/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_heap.h:305:4: error: no match for call to ‘(std::binary_function<int, int, bool>) (int&, int&)’`

---

edit:

I've also tried using a binary_function pointer and allocating on the heap, and now i get a different error:

```
template<typename T> inline void printheap (T* v, int begin, int end, bool max) {
    ...
    std::binary_function<T,T,bool> *comp;
    if (max) comp = new less<T>();
    else comp = new greater<T>();
    ...
        pop_heap(&v[begin], &v[end+1], (*comp) );
    ...
delete comp;
}
```

error:

`/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_heap.h:305:4: error: ‘__comp’ cannot be used as a function`

Comment: Also use `std::function` instead of `binary_function`, because the latter is deprecated in C++11. This may solve your problem.

Comment: i did forget to dereference, but doing so yields me the first compiler error again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are the victim of [object slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing).

When you assign `less<T>` or `greater<T>` to the `binary_function` type, the `operator()` they define is gone.

From [my favorite reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/binary_function):

> binary_function does not define operator(); it is expected that derived classes will define this. binary_function provides only three types - first_argument_type, second_argument_type and result_type - defined by the template parameters.

You should pass `less<T>` or `greater<T>` in directly. You can also use [`pointer_to_binary_function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/pointer_to_binary_function), but they've both been deprecated in C++11 in favor of [`function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

Comment: +1, but dereferencing the pointer would yield a reference to `binary_function` which doesn't define `operator()` so he'd get an error still. He should be using `std::function`.